# How does the circuit for the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor work?

Tags: arduino, sensor, hc-sr04

I already understand that the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor sends out a pulse and can be used to measure distance with the time of the echo. I want to know more about the actual physical construction of the sensor's circuit and how it works. I basically know how the sensor generally works but I want to have a deeper understanding.

Comment: The reverse-engineered module schematics can be found on the web. There is no deeper understanding, the schematics simply implement what you described already. You likely won't find the program for the MCU that runs on the board so you just need to use a higher level of understanding that it generates the tone burst and waits to see the echo back.